# Big Delay in ImapClient, SmtpClient and Pop3Client Connect method when using secure connection

Tags: mailkit

I notice up to 13 sec delay when trying to connect SMTP or IMAP client from MailKit. It seems the delay happens on the call to AuthenticateAsClient method inside MailKit library. I found explanation for the problem here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2011/09/27/big-delay-when-calling-sslstream-authenticateasclient/

This is not an issue in MailKit but I want to know the best workaround for this problem using MailKit. It seems cancellationToken passed to MailKit Connect method is not cancelling this method call. This is a problem when you want to shutdown your process while SmtpClient is connecting, because you want to wait the dedicated thread that runs this code to complete.

This is the workaround I have but it is not very elegant

```
public override void Connect(string host, int port = 0, SecureSocketOptions options = SecureSocketOptions.Auto, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var connectionTask = smtpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port, options, cancellationToken);

    Task.WhenAny(connectionTask, cancellationToken.WhenCanceled()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static Task WhenCanceled(this CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).SetResult(true), tcs);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

This above will work most of the time but if cancel the token the connection will stay in connecting state (because AuthenticateAsClient is not cancellable)  and the user might attempt to execute another command while the smtpClient is still trying to connect.

I am looking for better approach for cancelling the Connect method in the context of MailKit.

Comment: What if you set `client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false`? Does this still block?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't currently reproduce this. I believe the big delay depends on remote server which participate in certificate validation and the delay depends on that server load and currently i don't observe any delays.